# inverting product and sum

Tags: real-analysis, summation, summation-method

I am always having a hard time when I am dealing with expressions of the form :

> $$B(x) = \prod_{i = 1}^N \sum_{k = 1}^{L_i} a_{i, k}(x)$$
>   where $(L_n)$ is a sequence of naturals numbers such that : $L_i \geq 1$ and $(a_{i,j})$ is a sequence of functions.

Most of the time in order to get a better understanding we need to somehow do some tricks in order to invert $\sum$ and $\prod$ or in order to simply get rid of the $\prod$.

Yet I am always having a hard time getting $B$ into this form. So I am wondering is there a general formula or a strategy to get $B$ into this form ?

For example when dealing with power series we have the Cauchy-product which alows us to put an expression of the form :

$$\prod_{i = 1}^2 \sum_{k = 0}^n a_nx^n $$

into the form :

$$\sum_{k = 0}^{2n} x^k \sum_{i = 0}^k a_{k -i}a_i$$

Thank you !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have
$$\prod_{i = 1}^N \sum_{k = 1}^{L_i} a_{i, k}=\sum_{\ell}\prod_{i=1}^Na_{i,\ell(i)}$$
where the sum on the right runs over the functions
$$\ell:\{1,\ldots,N\}\to\Bbb N$$
such that $\ell(i)\leq L_i$ for every $i$.

---

More generally, we have for sets $I$ and $K_i$ for $i\in I$:
$$\prod_{i\in I}\sum_{k\in K_i}a_{i,k}=\sum_\ell\prod_{i\in I}a_{i,\ell(i)}$$
where the sum on the right runs over
$$\ell\in\prod_{i\in I}K_i$$
that's
$$\ell:I\to\bigcup_{i\in I}K_i$$
such that $\ell(i)\in K_i$ for every $i\in I$.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you.